# Форматирование текстового поля

Tags: jquery

Добрый день!

Есть поле ввода:

```
<input type="text" value="Введите номер" />
```

Необходимо, сделать следуещее:

Ввели так 79051234567 стало +7 (905) 123-45-67
Вводить можно как угодно, в результате должны получить форматированный номер - +7 (905) 123-45-67

Comment: Просто считать символы и после определенных вставлять нужные знаки препинания

Comment: Можете ещё попробовать http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ — гибкие настройки, все дела, но это именно маска ввода.

Answer (score 3):

Плагин, в этом случае, скорее всего, будет лучше, но я решил побаловаться и накатал [примитивный примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7xeQv/2/). Если захотите, то можете взять за основу.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('input').focusout(function(){
        var numb = $(this).val();
        var aNumb = numb.match(/\d/g);
        if (aNumb && aNumb.length==11){
            aNumb = aNumb.join('');
            var res = aNumb.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/g,'+$1 ($2) $3-$4-$5');
            $(this).val(res);
        }
    });
});
```